# When you install a node module using "npm install -g", where does npm put globally installed files?

Tags: linux, bash

When you install a node module using "npm install -g", where does npm put globally installed files?

Answer (score 2):

You can run `npm list -g` to see where global libraries are installed.

On Unix systems they are normally placed in `/usr/local/lib/node` or `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` when installed globally. If you set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable to this path, the modules can be found by node.

Windows XP - `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\npm\node_modules`

Windows 7, 8 and 10 - `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

Comment: i have tried `npm list -g` and didnt give me anything it says the comment is not found